# A weakly but not strongly convergent sequence in $H_0^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

I am looking for a sequence that weakly converges in $H_0^1$ but not strongly. I am not sure how to define a weakly convergent sequence in $H_0^1$ in the first place.

Comment: It's the same topology as $H^1$.  You want $\langle f_n-f, g \rangle$ to converge to 0 for any $g\in H_0^1$.

Comment: Alright, can you come up with a simple sequence of functions satisfying $\langle f_n-f,g \rangle =0$ but $f$ not being weakly differentiable?

Comment: I always try to play around with the "standard basis" in $L^2$ for questions like this.

Comment: @Chee Han
Interesting, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: It can be shown (and you should try to do this) that $(e_n)$ converges weakly to 0 in $L^2$, but it cannot converges strongly since $\|e_n-0\| = 1$ for any $n\ge 1$. In general, you can show that a set of mutually orthogonal unit vectors in a Hilbert space converges weakly to 0. One could see the main idea there: try to construct a sequence $f_n$ that converges weakly to 0 but $\|f_n\|=1$.

Comment: In general, the weak convergence in a normed space $X$ can be defined as: $u_n$ converges weakly to $u$ in $X$ iff $f(u_n)$ converges to $f(u)$ (in the scalar sense) for all $f\in X'$, where $X'$ is the continuous dual of $X$ (see [Kreyszig](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Introductory_Functional_Analysis_With_Ap.html?id=Va8rAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y), p. 256).....

Comment: .....The same definition applies to the case $X=H_0^1$. But in this case, $f$ has a particular integral representation (see, for example,  p. 283 of [Evans](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=evans+pde&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr1_Kr4t7TAhUFFJAKHYNCBr8Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=evans%20pde&f=false) or p. 291 of [Brezis](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brezis+pde+sobolev&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBxf-64t7TAhWCf5AKHc2gCIAQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=brezis%20pde%20sobolev&f=false)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H_0^1$ is infinite dimensional (I assume that the support of your measure is not a finite set), you may find $\{e_1, e_2, \dots\} \subset H_0^1$ linearly independent. Using [the Gram-Schmidt procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram.E2.80.93Schmidt_process) you may obtain an *orthonormal* subset $\{f_1, f_2, \dots\}$.

If the sequence $(f_n)$ were convergent (i.e. *strongly*), it would also be Cauchy. But

$$\| f_n - f_m \|^2 = \| f_n \|^2 - \langle f_n, f_m \rangle - \langle f_m, f_n \rangle + \| f_m \|^2 = 1 - 0 - 0 + 1 = 2 ,$$

which shows that the distance between any two terms of that sequence does not decrease, staying constant $\sqrt 2$, so the sequence is not Cauchy, therefore not convergent.

On the other hand, it is [a consequence of Alaoglu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Consequences) that the unit ball in any Hilbert space is *weakly* compact. Since $\| f_n \| = 1$ for all $n$, it follows that the sequence $(f_n)$ lives inside the unit ball of $H_0^1$. Since this one is weakly compact, [it follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Metric_spaces) that $(f_n)$ has a *weakly*-convergent subsequence, call it $(g_n)$. This $(g_n)$ is the sequence that you are looking for (it is not convergent for the same reason for which $(f_n)$ is not.)

Comment: It's worth to note that this argument only uses the fact that $H_0^1$ is a Hilbert space. So, if we replace the symbol $H_0^1$ by a symbol $H$ standing for an arbitrary Hilbert space, we will get the general result that, in any Hilbert space, weak convergence does not imply strong convergence. Also, there is a more elementary  argument for the topological argument in the last paragraph (which gives a stronger result), namely, applying the Riesz Representation Theorem and the Bessel's inequality (which shows that the sequence itself converges weakly (to zero)).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac1n\sin(2\pi nx)$ for $x\in (-1,1)$. Note that $f_n\to 0$ uniformly. Also, $f^{\prime}_n(x)=2\pi\cos(2\pi nx)$. Using the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, you have that $$\int_{-1}^1 2\pi\cos(2\pi nx)g(x)\,dx\to 0$$ for every function $g\in L^2(-1,1)$. This shows that $f_n$ converges to zero weakly in $H^1_0$. However, $f^{\prime}_n$ does not converge to $0$ in $L^2$, since $\int_{-1}^1 (2\pi\cos(2\pi nx))^2\,dx$ does not go zero, so you don't have strong convergence in $H^1_0$.

Comment: This is a right answer too.

Comment: @SaraWinslet If you are "looking for a sequence", as you said, this is **the** right answer because the [Alex's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2269583/70305) only proves that such a sequence exists.